# ASP.NET MVC and legacyCasModel=true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a fresh ASP.NET MVC4 website using a proprietary API that tells me I need to include `<trust level="Full" legacyCasModel="true"/>` in my Web.config file. When I do this, however, the application exceptions out with the message "Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain" I have poked around a bit and it seems that this has to do with some dynamic calls not being allowed.

My question is: Does that mean I have to abandon MVC altogether and make my site with Web Forms?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can move the code which calls the API to separate DLL, make your calls there and expose that DLL as a web service (or .NET Remoting or whatever works). Then, from your MVC web-app, call your new web service in order to reach the proprietary API.

Basically, wrap the API calls in a (local) web service call.

This approach would allow you to use MVC instead of WebForms. It does add some complexity and overhead, but I think the pros (ability to use MVC) outweigh the cons.